# How the files can have different umask value when upload the ftp though vsftpd?

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

Now, I want upload wordpress files to my VPS by vsftpd, and I know different files have different umask value in wordpress, and when I set the default umask in vsftpd configure file. such as set "local_umask=022", and all upload files umask value will become 644.

Answer (score 0):

Umask is a filter (a mask, hence the name), not the actual permissions. Writing a file with requested permissions 0666 and an umask of 022 will result in actual permissions 0644.